# In Mercurial, how to check what version of a file a branch has?

Tags: mercurial

I am only interested in the history of a single file. I tried hg log already, which shows all the changes made to the file. But if there was a branch made of the entire repository, how do I know from log (short of checking out the entire repository in that branch and then looking at the file and manually compare to the different check-ins in head) which version of the file (i.e. at what point along the head) that branch got?

(I have also tried googling to no avail. Maybe I'm not using the right search terms as I am new to Mercurial. I hope I have explained my goal clearly though.)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `glog` command:

```
$ hg glog foo.py
```

Note that you'll need to enable the `graphlog` extension, by adding `hgext.graphlog =` to the `[extensions]` heading of your `~/.hgrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.hgrc
[extensions]
hgext.graphlog =
…
$
```

A simple, manual, way to figure out when a branch was taken is to run:

```
$ hg glog
```

Then search for the filename and see which changesets it's changed in.

Alternatively, you could run:

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(mybranch)' myfile
```

To show you all the changesets both in and before mybranch which contain changes to `myfile`, then look for the last changeset that modifies the file before the branch was taken:

```
$ hg log -r 'ancestors(mybranch)' myfile
changeset:   30:3b2f7243c1ac
user:        David Wolever <david@wolever.net>
date:        Mon Nov 15 09:47:46 2010 -0500
files:       myfile
description:
doing stuff


changeset:   31:804257c328ab <-- last change to the file before the branch
user:        David Wolever <david@wolever.net>
date:        Thu Nov 18 21:44:11 2010 -0500
files:       myfile
description:
changing things

changeset:   32:df26ccd32c38 <-- change was made to the file in the branch
branch:      mybranch
user:        David Wolever <david@wolever.net>
date:        Thu Nov 18 23:23:44 2010 -0500
files:       myfile anotherfile
description:
starting mybranch
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this functionality before. However, I tried this, and this still doesn't show the branches with no commits, only the branches that had changes.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part of the question. As @Ry4an says — that doesn't really make sense in Mercurial. I've updated my answer a bit, though, so hopefully it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking in 'svn' (or CSV) terms.  Your question doesn't make sense in the context of Mercurial (or git).  Individual files don't have versions in either of these DVCSs.  Versions are called revisions and are repository-wide.  You can't "checkout" revision X of one file and revision Y of another like you can in svn.

So a question similar to yours what would make sense might be "What revision most recently change file X in branch Y" and one way to get that answer would be:

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(Y)' X
```

or

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(default)' TODO
```

with some concrete values.

Comment: Sorry, but your command **must be** polished - your revset returns list of changesets, not single result

Comment: "You can't "checkout" revision X of one file and revision Y of another" - **you can not**, I can (to some degree) - `hg revert -r N FILE`

Comment: @LazyBadger that's not "checkout".  Checkout has firm semantics w/r/t dirstate in mercurial and revert only touches the working dir.  It's not checked out.

Comment: I said from user-side, from which "dirstate" is just useless noise - user want to get **result** and revert is some iteration to SNN's "sparse checkout"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you want, but you can list all revisions that contain a specific filename using either

```
hg log -r "contains(filename)"
```

or

```
hg glog -r "contains(filename)"
```

If you want something more specific, check out the `hg help revsets` output, which shows the possibilities of the `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

For Ry4an's text of task revset for log have to be

```
"max(branch(Y) & contains(X))"
```

Comment: Thanks. Though contains() seems to return all revisions that had the file, not just where the file was modified. I looked through the documentation and it seems like it should be file(X) instead of contains(X). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @welkin - I can't recall difference between contains() and file(): both are about file-pattern'ed search of files in changesets. Yes, contains() about "file in changeset", but how you'll get *unmodified* file in changeset? Anyway, purists may use `modifies(X)`